# How should I document my react application?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, documentation, jsdoc

I am making a React app for a personal project, and I pretend to release it as a real application.

So ***I'm wondering*** if I have to document my React components for those other people that could read and take a look at my project.

I already know about a few documentation tools like JSDoc, but I don't know if they apply to React.js specifically.

***And what about custom hooks?*** Mine seems a bit complicated to understand, and maybe a documentation tool might be useful in this case. I haven't seen anybody use documentation on custom hooks, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSDoc is still pretty standard. Have a look, [React itself uses it](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/9cdf8a99edcfd94d7420835ea663edca04237527/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L128-L148):

[image: react jsdoc]

Whether the other folks in your team will actually consume these comments as JSDoc or just regular comments depends entirely on their IDEs (or if you export your JSDocs using [some tool](https://github.com/jsdoc2md/jsdoc-to-markdown) and publish them).

And, yes, this applies to custom hooks as well.